# ¿Se puede rimar de forma asonante una palabra llana con una esdrújula?

Tags: poesía, rima

Me encuentro leyendo [una composición](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003764719&page=6&lang=es) con estructura de [romance](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WdT7nIL), y veo que las vocales que se han escogido para la rima asonante son *a* y *o*, usando para la rima palabras llanas: *fandango, planos, llorado, amo, abro, simplonazo, caso*, etc. Sin embargo, en un momento dado intercala en dicha rima asonante la palabra *[jácaro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MHVnpdj)*.

Sé que las palabras esdrújulas restan una unidad al número de sílabas del verso, pero ignoro cómo se tratan cuando intervienen en una rima asonante. Pensaba que las rimas asonantes, si se escogen dos vocales para la rima, debían ser siempre compuestas por palabras llanas. Pero veo que no, aunque me resulta raro que las vocales usadas de la palabra esdrújula (*jácaro*) sean la primera (*a*) y la tercera (*o*). Pensaba que las vocales que intervendrían serían la acentuada y la siguiente (en ese caso, serían dos *a*).

Así pues, ¿puede una palabra llana rimar de forma asonante con una esdrújula? Si es así, ¿cuáles son las reglas para que se considere efectiva dicha rima?

Comment: @walen incluyo un enlace al poema al principio de la pregunta. En todo caso, era solo por poner un ejemplo, la pregunta pretendía que fuese genérica.

Comment: No tengo un ejemplo a la memoria, pero técnicamente «es fea / comprémonosla» rima con el patrón E-A (siempre es la tónica y la última, y en casos de ser la misma, se contemplan vocales «fantasma», como «capitán» que tiene la rima A-O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí puede rimar una palabra esdrújula con una llana, es un tipo de rima parcial, llamada «rima de  perceptibilidad degradada». He encontrado en varias páginas el mismo texto, no sé cuál será la fuente original:

> La rima parcial, por su timbre, se califica de perceptibilidad degradada, en los siguientes casos:
>
> Cuando rima una palabra grave con una esdrújula, la rima se produce entre la vocal tónica y la final de ambas palabras, quedando sin rimar la vocal intermedia de la palabra esdrújula.
>   Ejemplo:
>
> *Arriba a ti la voz de sus discípulos*
>   *rogando por Jesús, que les revela*
>   *su muerte, su cercano sacrificio*
>   *para acatar la ley de las estrellas.*
>
> La palabra *discípulos*, esdrújula, rima con *sacrificio*. La rima es "i-o", la vocal intermedia de las sílabas postónicas de la palabra esdrújula no influye en la rima asonante.

Comment: Cuando yo aprendí la poesía, nos enseñaron a descartar la vocal intermedia (no solo por la cualidad vocal, sino en contando el número de sílabas, la palabra «discípulos» por situarse al final del verso, solo le aporta, a efectos métricos, tres sílabas).